# Azure Portal VM Subscription

Tags: azure

I purchased an Azure pay-as-you-go subscription for a VM.  When I login to my Azure portal account I don't see the VM listed under my virtual machines.

Comment: Could you please check activity log via Azure portal?

Answer (score 0):

One of the things worth checking is that you are logged in with the:

1. **Correct account**. Make sure that you are signed in with the right Microsoft account - you can select it in the upper right corner.
2. **Have the correct subscription selected**. This is especially important if you have multiple subscriptions.

Also, VMs take some time to create - make sure that the process is complete after you kicked off a new provisioning.

Comment: thanks for your response.  I am logged into the correct account.  I see the subscription.  When I'm on the VM's page, I have the "All Subscriptions" checked (i see the subscription for my VM in the list ...it's checked).  Yet, no VM's are listed.

Comment: @s15199d did you actually create a new VM?

Comment: apparently I created a pay-as-you-go subscription, which I thought would spin up a VM matching the selections I made for the pay-as-you-go subscription. Apparently that's not how it works. I'm still working thru it with Azure support.  I see how to create a resource in the Azure portal, but then what's the purpose of the pay-as-you-go subscription i created and paid for?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible, I think you can open a case from your Azure subscription.